# SQL Server: Can I filter BCP usage in logon trigger?

Tags: sql-server, authentication, triggers, bcp

I need to intercept and block command line utilities ( BCP, SQLCMD, ... ) from unauthorized servers or users.
For SQLCMD it has ApplicationName = "SQLCMD" , so it's easy to filter.
BCP.EXE instead has ApplicationName = "Microsoft SQL Server" , so I can't filter for "BCP" .

Is there any trick to block only BCP in Logon trigger?
Thanks

Moreno

Comment: Anyone could get past an `ApplicationName` if they wanted to. Or do you want to just remind users that they are not supposed to do this?

Comment: Hi Charlieface,
I know this can be easily bypassed, but my users are not so skilled and I suppose they don't want to be fraudolent.
I need to allow BCP usage only from authorized servers and users